# C++ convert char array of digits and commas to list of integers?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, int

I have a socket setup in C++ that receives a stream of chars in a buffer array

```
char buffer[MAXSIZE];
```

the characters in `buffer` can only be digits `0`,`1`,...,`9` or a comma `,`. I would like to convert an example buffer content such as

```
buffer = {'1','2' , ',' , '3' , ',' , '5','6' , ...};
```

where the final char position is stored in a variable `len`, to a list of integers

```
integers = {12 , 3 , 56};
```

I can hack together a dumb way of doing this by iterating through the list of chars, taking each digit, multiplying it by 10 and adding the next digit, until I encounter a comma `,`. But I guess this approach would be too slow for large data rate.

What is the proper way of doing this conversion in C++?

Comment: 1) Convert to `std::stringstream`.  2) Use `std::getline()` with a comma as delimiter (although this is not necessary).  3) Or you could read the number followed by reading the comma.

Comment: `But I guess this approach would be too slow for large data rate.` _too slow_? How could you do it _faster_?

Comment: It's amazing how fast the dumb way can be when it goes in a more-or-less straight line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use the range-v3 library, you could do this:

```
namespace rs = ranges;
namespace rv = ranges::views;

auto integers = buffer 
                | rv::split(',') 
                | rv::transform([](auto&& r) { 
                      return std::stoi(r | rs::to<std::string>); 
                  }) 
                | rs::to<std::vector<int>>;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fGoWKx).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that a `std::vector` can be used, you can try this:

```
std::vector<int> integers;
int currentNumber = 0;
for(char c = ' ', int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++) {
    c = buffer[i];
    if(c == ',') {
        integers.push_back(currentNumber);
        currentNumber = 0;
    } else {
        currentNumber *= 10;
        currentNumber += c - '0';
    }
}
integers.push_back(currentNumber);
```

Comment: @Kagaratsch If it works for you, please accept this answer

Comment: What about negative numbers?